# Panada groupby, then apply function to compare consecutive values(starting bottom to top) for increase, new column to be created stating true/false

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

> Here is my data. Q - Y/Y Eps is the quarter growth compared to last
> years quarter.
> I want to create a new column named 'Increase Eps Growth' that has true and false
> values base on whether Q - Y/Y Eps is increasing. The stocks symbols must be
> grouped based on symbol and the comparison must start from the bottom up.

```
          Date Symbol Period   Eps       Revenue     Rev Cost  Q - Y/Y Eps
0       2021-04-30      A     Q2  0.71  1.525000e+09  708000000.0       115.15
1       2021-01-31      A     Q1  0.94  1.548000e+09  710000000.0        46.87
2       2020-10-31      A     Q4  0.72  1.483000e+09  695000000.0        14.29
3       2020-07-31      A     Q3  0.64  1.261000e+09  592000000.0         4.92
4       2020-04-30      A     Q2  0.33  1.238000e+09  581000000.0       -42.11
...            ...    ...    ...   ...           ...          ...          ...
277476  1999-03-31   ZYXI     Q1 -0.00  0.000000e+00          0.0          NaN
277477  1998-12-31   ZYXI     Q4 -0.00  0.000000e+00          0.0          NaN
277478  1998-09-30   ZYXI     Q3 -0.00  3.259000e+03       1629.0          NaN
277479  1998-06-30   ZYXI     Q2 -0.00  4.455000e+03       2228.0          NaN
277480  1998-03-31   ZYXI     Q1 -0.00  4.702000e+03       2350.0          NaN
[277481 rows x 7 columns]
```

> My current code is...

```
df['Increase Eps Growth'] = df.groupby(by='Symbol')['Q - Y/Y Eps'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x.shift(-2) > x.shift(-1) else 'False')
```

> And I get the following error and am not sure how to fix it. How can I
> fix this so the truth value is not ambiguous? I'm also unsure why I
> might be getting this error.

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

> I have also tried...

```
df['Increase Eps'] = df.groupby(by='Symbol').transform(np.where(df['Q - Y/Y Eps'].shift(-2) > df['Q - Y/Y Eps'].shift(-1), 'True', 'False'
```

> And I get the following error
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
>
> ```
> I'm newer to Pandas and any help or sight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
> ```

Comment: use `lambda x: x.shift(-2) > x.shift(-1)` in `groupby` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

via `groupby()` and `transform()`:

```
df['Increase Eps']=(df.groupby(by='Symbol')['Q - Y/Y Eps']
                      .transform(lambda x:x.shift(-2) > x.shift(-1)))
```

**OR**

via via `groupby()` and `apply()`:

```
df['Increase Eps']=(df.groupby(by='Symbol')['Q - Y/Y Eps']
                      .apply(lambda x:x.shift(-2) > x.shift(-1)))
```